# Vertices movement keeping view perspective, but not actually moving the vertices

Tags: mesh

I'm currently making the plate from the donut tutorial available by the blender guru on youtube. Here's the link: https://youtu.be/SBtDix7xGOg?t=733. We are creating a plate from a solidified circle. I'm on the step where you're creating the spot for the tea cup to rest, which involves the movement of a vertices loop in the "z" direction. I pressed "g", then "z" to move the loop similar to what's shown in the second image. If you look at it from a different view, however, it seems like the vertices moved in a manner that would make it seem like the loop moved in the "z" direction, when instead they just smeared on the surface of the plate in 2-D. (First image) Has anyone else experienced this issue?[image] [image]

Comment: you've enabled the snapping option (magnet icon), are you sure it doesn't mess with your G?

Comment: That's what it was! Thank you very much!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Disable the *Snapping* option (magnet icon).

[Snapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#snapping) makes your selection snap to the face.